# Doesnot throw any exception even the value inside 'try' method returns 'false' in webdriver

Tags: c#, exception, webdriver

```
try
{
     driver.FindElement(By.XPath("")).Text.Contains(string Count);
}
catch (Exception)
{
     throw new Exception("Publication Count not matching");
}
```

This is my script. The count is not matches with the value getting from the xpath. But the above function is not throws exception. Why so?

Answer (score 2):

No exception is thrown because no illegal actions are being executed. All is being executed normally, but with no result.

I think you are looking for an `if-statement`:

```
if(!driver.FindElement(By.XPath("")).Text.Contains(string Count))
{
     throw new Exception("Publication Count not matching");
}
```

Also, you are throwing a new exception which gets rid of the original stacktrace, which is never a good thing because this stacktrace may get you information you really require.

If you are interested in finding out more information regarding exceptions and exceptionhandling, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx) is a good place to start.